# allignment of text on canvas in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to display score and level for a game on canvas. For that I used the following piece of code:

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
             canvas.drawText("Score: -" + score +
                                  "    Level: -" + level + "    
                                           Chances:-" + chances, 0, 0, paint);
```

Now when the score and level gets updated, the width of this line increases. So set its starting point at (o, o).

But at the starting of the game, it looks as if it is left aligned.

Is there any way to make the the string's alignment JUSTIFIED??

Answer (score 0):

That will make it center, you may have to change where it is being drawn at though. Align only has options for LEFT, RIGHT, and CENTER. I'm not sure if there is a way to get it justified.

```
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
```